# SQL, sum one column where another column is the same and display as the third column

Tags: sql-server, aggregate

I have the following data:

```
a  b
1  23
1  14
1  3
2  45
2  16
```

and what I would like is to sum column b where column a is the same and have this displayed in a third column, like so:

```
a  b  c
1  23 40
1  14 40
1  3  40
2  45 61
2  16 61
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't specify your RDBMS, but here is a solution using SQL Server

```
Declare @T table (a int, b int)
INSERT INTO @T
    (a, b)
VALUES
    (1, 23),
    (1, 14),
    (1, 3),
    (2, 45),
    (2, 16)
;

select 
    a,b,sum(b) over (partition by a)  as c
from @T
```

---

```
| a | b  | c  |
|---|----|----|
| 1 | 23 | 40 |
| 1 | 14 | 40 |
| 1 | 3  | 40 |
| 2 | 45 | 61 |
| 2 | 16 | 61 |
```

---

If your RDBMS doesn't support Window Functions, you could use a common table expression to do the sum/group and then join that `cte` to the original table.  The results are the same.

```
;WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT a
        ,sum(b) AS c
    FROM @T
    GROUP BY a
    )
SELECT t.a
    ,t.b
    ,c.c
FROM @T t
JOIN _cte c ON c.a = t.a
```

Comment: Yes, SQL server.  The first solution worked.  Thanks very much!

Comment: Sorry, new to this, as you can probably tell!

Comment: @Jimothous - take the tour, visit the help centre. Read [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2990/minimal-complete-and-verifiable-example) and [this](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql) carefully - for future reference, for this type of question, it  would be great if you could provide a fiddle. These sites are a great resource and you will get all the more out of them if you follow the guidelines - p.s. welcome to the forum!